# Tracking progress in python list(map(...))

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar

I am attempting to track progress in the following code:

```
from toolz import compose
calculator = compose(my_function, list, my_dict.get, tuple)
result = list(zip(*map(calculator, my_values)))
```

`my_values` is a list of length ~1mio. My first attempt is to add a counter to `my_function` that increments and print it out when a multiple of X (e.g. `X==500`) is reached.

Is there a pythonic or cleaner way to achieve this, i.e. without adding lots of counters to various loops? A progress bar in jupyter notebook would work too.

Comment: Are you just asking for a way to identify multiples of `x`? If so, modulus: `if value % x == 0:`.

Comment: @jack6e, that's exactly what I've been doing. However, (a) code gets messy with these loops (counters which aren't part of logic), (b) you also have to modify x depending on number of items in your input.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a progress bar in Jupyter will work, I like to use `tqdm`, as it works for any iterable.  Here is some sample code (slightly simplified from your example since I had to write `my_function`, `my_values`, etc):

```
def my_function(x):
    yield x + 2

my_values = range(1000000)

result = list(zip(*map(my_function, my_values)))
```

Now just add tqdm on `my_values` (no progress checkers/counters clogging up your code!) to get a nice progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def my_function(x):
    yield x + 2

my_values = tqdm(range(1000000))

result = list(zip(*map(my_function, my_values)))
```

which rolls through the awesome tqdm progress bar:

```
100%|██████████| 1000000/1000000 [00:04<00:00, 210661.41it/s]
```

Note I have nothing to do with the tqdm project; I just like using it.  https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: This works, thanks. Just to add, for others looking for similar solutions, if you need to apply a function lazily to many items in an iterable, then dask.delayed may help, and the dask library also has a built-in ProgressBar.

Comment: what if my function has more than one argument?

Comment: to answer my comment:
ust apply **tqdm** to only one of the multiple arguments, for instance, 
```result = list(zip(*map(my_function, tqdm( range(1000000) ), some_other_argument)))```

Answer (score 0):

While using map in DataFrames, use tqdm.pandas() and then in place of map() do use progress_map() and progress_apply() in place of apply()